# How to create round plus minus using css?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code which has plus and minus image to display toggle, how can make this purely CSS based so plus and minus are bold and circular and not image based.

HTML

```
<div class="toggle">
Show and hide < plus minus icon will show here> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
toggle{
    display:inline-block;
    /*height:48px;
    width:48px;*/
    background:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pixelmixer/basic/48/plus-icon.png") no-repeat scroll 183px 0 transparent
}
.toggle:after{
    content:"View All";
    display:block;
    height:48px;
    line-height:48px;
    width:288px;
    margin-left:48px;

}
.toggle.expanded:after{
     content:"Close All ";
}
.toggle.expanded {
  background:url("http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_32.png") no-repeat scroll 183px 0 ;

}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $content = $("div.moreinfo").hide();

  $(".toggle").on("click", function(e) {
     $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
     if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
        $("div.plus").hide().removeClass("closed");
        $("div.minus").show().addClass("opened");
        e.preventDefault();
     } else {
        $("div.plus").show().addClass("closed");
        $("div.minus").hide().removeClass("opened");
        e.preventDefault();

     }
     $content.slideToggle();

  });
});
```

Comment: Please review your post before submitting. I see lots of errors, which could be handled if you read your post before submitting it.

Comment: Also, I'm having a hard time understanding what you want. Do you want to make a positive and negative character in CSS, then make them bold? So you can replace your two images?

Comment: Yes I want to make positive and negative both in bold.

Comment: "plus and minus are bold and circular" I think he wants the symbols inside a circle. Like Windows Phone icons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't like having a text on `:after` and `:before`. 
Instead of having those messages it's better to put those symbols there.

**So from:**

```
.toggle:after{
    content:"View All Violations";
}
```

**To:**

```
.toggle:after{
    content:"+";
}
```

And

```
.toggle.expanded:after{
     content:"Close All Violations";
}
```

**To :**

```
.toggle.expanded:after{
     content:"-";
}
```

Then to make those symbols look good, add styles like

`font-weight:bold` and `font-size: 48px`

As for the messages have those inside an element `span` instead

```
<span class="message">View All Violations</span>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fresyLsa/)

Comment: thanks that what i was exactly looking was to change the plus and minus and the text on toggle.

Answer (score -1):

I honestly don't know what you're asking.

http://jsfiddle.net/a93jjzvL/

```
#positive:after {
    content: "+";
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

By using content in the CSS, you can change the content. Do that, make it bold, and I should've answered your question. Which makes no sense. Of course, now you need to add the appropriate CSS to style it, but we're here to teach.. not babysit.